# Arithmetic on char* in python with pybind11

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pybind11

Let's say I have a binary parser in C++ wrapped with pybind11 to read packed structs out of binary sequence.

C++ code:

```
class Reader {
    FILE* m_fp;
public:
    void open(const char* file) { /* open a binary file */ }
    const char* get_data() { /* the content of the file */ }
};

struct HEADER {
    char* m_data;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

pybind11

```
py::class_<Reader>(m, "Reader")
.def(py::init<>)
.def("open", &Reader::open)
.def("get_data", &Reader::get_data)

py::class_<Parser>(m, "HEADER")
.def_static("from_bytes", [](const char* data) { return reinterpret_cast<HEADER*>(data); } )
.def_static_advance("advance", [](const char* data, const uint32_t skip, const uint32_t length) { return py::bytes(data + skip, length); } )
```

In my python code:

```
reader = Reader()
reader.open("/tmp/abc.bin");
data = reader.get_data();
hdr = Parser.from_bytes()
data = Parser.advance(data, sizeof(HEADER), remaining_length)
for i in range(hdr.m_num_msgs):
    msg = MSG.from_buffer_copy(data)
    remaining_length = remaining_length - sizeof(MSG)
    data = Parser.advance(data, sizeof(MSG), remaining_length)
```

Few questions:

1. Is it okay to pass `py::bytes` object from C++ to python and then back to C++ as a `const char*` to do the arithmetic like I did in the code?
2. Is there a better/more efficient way to extract packed c struct data one by one?
3. `py::bytes` seems to make a copy, is there a way not to make a copy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code example is missing some parts. For example, you write a binding for a class called "Parser" but I don't see a definition for it. You have labelled it "HEADER"?

1. This is okay. If you look in pytypes.h, you will see a constructor for a `py::bytes` object, which takes a `const char*`. So PyBind11 will automatically do any conversions here for you.
   See here for more detail:
   https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/strings.html#return-c-strings-without-conversion
2. I don't know, sorry.
3. Copying is inherently part of the C++ -> Python process that PyBind11 uses, due to the difference in how C++ and Python do memory management. However, consider reading this, I believe it provides some different return policies which may allow some optimisation in this case: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html#return-value-policies

Finally, that use of `reinterpret_cast` makes me nervous, I do wonder if that's undefined behaviour. Maybe something along these lines is what you want to do?:
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/strings.html#return-c-strings-without-conversion